# Different behaviours for $(window).scroll function on page scroll

Tags: jquery, symfony1, scroll

I have a web application built using Symfony 1.4 and Mysql DB. I am using this code to detect if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page, send a request to get more results and then append the result:

jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var offset = 10;
    var noMore = true;
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //load more feeds on page scroll end
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        if($('.noFeeds').html()!='No feeds to show') // div shown when initially there are no feeds to show. In that case, we don't call the more feeds function
        {
          if($('#noMore').length) //check if the div that says there are no more feeds, exists or not
          {
           noMore = false; //if it does, set the flag to false so that the function to get more feeds is not called
          }
          if(noMore)
          {
            $('#loading').show();
            offset = offset+10;
            $.post("/user/getMoreFeeds?refferrer=home&offset="+offset+"&id="+<?php echo        $userId;?>, {
             }, function(response){
               $('#moreFeeds').append(response);
               $('#loading').hide();
            });
          }
        }
    }
  });
</script>
```

In the function getMorefeeds, I run a query to get more feeds using offset value and then display it in a partial. The partial is returned as the response. The code executed inside the partial is something like this:

PHP:

```
if(count($feeds)>0)
{
  // Show feeds
}
else
{
  <div id="noMore" class="activity_post" align="center" style="color:#A8A8A8;">No more   feeds to show</div>
}
```

When I scroll down the page slowly, I get everything properly and at the end the message is displayed "No  more feeds to show." , i.e. the div with id "noMore" is displayed.

However, if the page is scrolled quickly, I see that the div with id "noMore" is added twice. Could you please help me in figuring out this behaviour?

Comment: Please don't add `{SOLVED]` to the questions. Marking an answer as Accepted is enough to show that the problem has been solved.

Comment: Oh ! I am sorry. I wasn't aware of that. I thought that adding [SOLVED] would help. I'll edit the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do it like this

```
$(window).scroll(function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); #do sth });
```